# Domain values of inverse funtion

Tags: functions

If I'm plotting $$y=3e^{{x\over3}+1}$$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$ and on the same axes I want to plot its inverse $$y=3\ln\left({x\over3}\right)-3$$ but only for the domain values of $x$ given by the range of $f$

Would the inverse domain range be $x=8.15$ to $x=11.38$?

Comment: If you meant $y = 3e^{\frac{\color{red}{x}}{3} + 1}$, then the domain of the inverse is correct.

Comment: You are correct.

More precisely, the range of the inverse would be $x=3e$ and $x=3e^{\frac43}$